# TradingView crawler API about the account profile and post/comment content

Tags: python, web-crawler, tradingview-api

According to this paper [Misbehavior and Account Suspension in an Online Financial Communication Platform](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3543507.3583385)

They access the data of TradingView from APIs, especially the suspended account would return the "permanently_suspended" JSON field.

But I can't find any related APIs about the crawler of the account profile and post/comment content. :(

Instead, there are almost about the stock price or chart which I don't need.

Someone can help me find this API?